# How to determine the order of the file in the MSI cabinet?

Tags: windows-installer

During installation MSI checks if the order in the cabinets matches the Sequence column in the File table.

How to determine "the order in the cabinets" here ???

I am facing an issue -- the file "ABCFILE" is not found in the cabinet "XYZ.CAB"
even if that file is present in the "XYZ.CAB"

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that the order of files in the File table in your MSI exactly matches the order of the files (sequentially) in the filelist.txt file used when you create your cab using cabarc.exe.

So... your cab creation commmand looks like this:

%ROOT_DIR%\tools\cabsdk\BIN\CABARC.EXE n mycab.cab @filelist.txt

where filelist.txt is a list of files to put in the cab ordered exactly the same as in the File table in your msi file.

Comment: It is the windows installer who creates those CABs, right? We cannot create those outside of the wix compilation. Then, how can we ensure that the file sequence is correct?